# Can I use make(chan someStruct) in go?

Tags: go, struct, deadlock, channel, goroutine

for example:

```
type name struct {
    name string
    age int
}

func main() {
      c := make(chan name)

      c <- name{"sfsaf", 1}
      a, b := <- c

      close(c)
}
```

The result:

> fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

I want to pass values through channel. What should I do?

Comment: [Channel](https://golang.org/ref/spec#ChannelType) is used when communicating between concurrent functions. In your sample, write and read operation are not concurrent, thus resulting deadlock. Perform read or write inside a `goroutine` , e.g. `go func() { c <- name{"sfsaf", 1} }()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505012/go-fatal-error-all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock.

Comment: @CeriseLimón It's not a duplicate question. That one didn't show how to use `make(chan somestruct)` .

Comment: @putu Thanks , I will try. What do you think of `make(chan non-empty-struct)`

Comment: There is no reason to `close` the channel, unless you are signaling your receive that there will be no more values (e.g. with a `for range` loop).  See my answer posted below, updated with more details on how to use channels.

Comment: If you add a capacity to the channel, e.g. `make(chan name, 10)`, then you can send an element without having a goroutine waiting. It will be put in a queue.

Comment: That's a good point @md2perpe, and one I forgot to mention in my answer: buffered channels.

Comment: @md2perpe good idea

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes you can pass structs. But that's not the problem in your OP.

You sent a value on a channel, when there was no receiver ready to receive.  That is what caused your deadlock.

Channels expect the `receiver` to be blocking, waiting for the `sender`.  This is done with Goroutines.

Therefore, wrap your sender in a goroutine, which will not execute right away.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type name struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan name)

    go func() {
        c <- name{"sfsaf", 1}
        close(c)
    }()

    for n := range c {
        fmt.Println(n)
    }

    fmt.Println("channel was closed (all done!).")
}
```

See it in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/uaSuCaB4Ms

This works because the sender's goroutine is not executing yet.  Not until the current goroutine executing gets blocked.

And we get blocked on the `for n := range c` loop.  This is the receiver, sitting and waiting for values.  (It is a common pattern to use the for loop to iterate over channel values as it will sit and block, waiting for values).

So now that we are blocked waiting to receive values in the `for` loop, the inline gorouting will now execute, to send our value on the channel.

In addition, we follow safe practices and tidy up after ourselves and `close(c)` the channel, signalling the `for` loop or `select` statement that there will be no more values sent.  ***The sender always closes, never the receiver***. This is the pattern the `for` range loop uses to exit the for loop, and continue executing the rest of your code.

---

As a side note, you did well by passing the value of the struct - not a pointer.

If you passed a pointer, you'd have to implement some mutex lock around the object to prevent a R/W panic.

*[Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating.](https://blog.golang.org/share-memory-by-communicating)*

Stick to passing values, not pointers, around your channels and goroutines and reap the benefits.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I wonder how to get an element of struct. In this example, I want to get <-c.age which leads to this error : c.name undefined (type chan name has no field or method age)

Comment: I got it, one should use (<-c).age to get the certain element of the struct

Comment: how can you guarantee that above code always works? other words, what is the guarantee that the goroutine above the for loop will be executed after hitting the for loop?

Comment: @user1870400 it's by design of the language.  as Golang is a procedural (e.g. imperative) language by design, it executes order of operations sequentially.  within the Golang spec (can't find the link atm), the `go func()` instruction is deferred for execution until the current goroutine is blocked - which happens on the `for n := range c` operation in the code listed above.  to ease the confusion a bit, every operation, including `main()`, is executing within a goroutine. your entire app is running within a single goroutine, until you call `go func()` - now you'll have two goroutines.